# Blender beta 2.8: How can I insert a rim on this flat edge?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

[image: spout with flat polygon edge]

I would like to double the amount of vertices along the edge, with faces, to form a kind of "rim" or "depth" here. What type of 3d operations do I need to perform in order to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Select all vertices of the rim, then press E,S and move the mouse to scale inwward the new extruded faces; left click to confirm the scaling. Another method is to add a solidify modifier to the whole mesh.

Comment: How do I select the vertices? I don't see anything in the Select menu. https://i.imgur.com/4BvfDuj.png

Comment: Alt click on an edge of the edge loop, or C circle select, or B box select, or manually one by one holding Shift (in your case C and B work only in vertex select mode, not edge select mode).